# Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'ns1:customTargeting'

Tags: adsense, google-dfp

I am trying to push multiple creatives with custom targets. It works fine when I push a single creative. But when I try to push more than one creative, DFP throws this error

```
'Error: Unmarshalling Error:cvc-complex-type.3.2.2Attribute 'id' is not allowed to appear in element 'ns1:customTargeting'.'
```

Been looking around for any forums related to such errors but without any luck. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the forum where DFP API developers answer such questions:
[Google's DoubleClick for Publishers API Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated.